# How to make tensorflow oneHot in c++?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, tensorflow

In my image detection python code i am using this

```
xlabel = tf.one_hot(1, nClass).eval()
```

Now i am using c++ to get the model working on iOS.
Can anyone give me the c++ code snippet to which can do the same thing?
My aim is to get oneHot object whose size is lets say 60. on value is 1 and off value is 0.

Comment: Have you checked documentation? It is very easy to find C++ version of function:  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/one-hot.

Comment: Yes I checked the documentation, but as i am a newbie to this I couldn't figure out how to use it in my code specially I don't know what is 'tensorflow::Scope' how to declare it in my code and use it.

Comment: Show your current C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i couldn't do it from Tensorflow C++ direct API but i found a work around. If it can help someone else like me here it is:

```
std::vector<float> oneHotVec;
for(int i = 0; i < 62 ; i++)
{
    if (i == question)
        oneHotVec.push_back(1.0f);
    else
        oneHotVec.push_back(0.0f);
}
tensorflow::Tensor z(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape({1, 62}));
for (auto j = 0; j < 62; j++)
{ 
    z.matrix<float>().operator()(0, j) = oneHotVec.at(j);
}
```

Here "z" is one hot vector that tensor needs.